# Pandas Dataframe string based rules on 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rules

what would be the best method for applying a rule base like this:

> column 1 column 2 column3    new column

> Negative Negative Negative = Negative

> Neutral Neutral Neutral = Neutral

> Positive Positive Positive = Positive

> Negative Negative neutral = Negative

> Negative Negative Positive = Neutral

> Negative Positive Positive = Neutral

> Negative Neutral Neutral = Neutral

I have tried so far using if/else statement and numpy.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0), are there any better ways, **my goal would be to create a new column as shown above from column 1, 2 and 3 with the rules above applied**

Comment: [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as you said is the way to go.

Comment: What was the problem with your if/else and numpy.select?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I have tried using that already as can be reflected in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @not_speshal Not really problems but it seems that I would have to list many many rules in order for me to get all the probabilities, is there no faster way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: `np.select` is indeed the best way.

Comment: Okay thank you much appreciated then

Comment: @Jamr why does `Negative Negative Positive = Neutral` and `Negative Positive Positive = Neutral`? Are there actual weights to each category that you can sum? negative= -1; positive = 1; neutral = 0